# PHP & MYSQL - Limit user in database per day?

Tags: mysql

Ok, so I'm struggling here. So I'm setting up a little project, where a user can filter & search for whatever he wants . E.G Searches hello for 10 searches (10 results to be shown)

So after all of that I need to add the INT that he's searched (results fetched) and + it with the other current value that's under his primary ID for that user via INSERT.

And how would I reset the value per day? Will this need to be done manually? or can I do it automatically via MySQL?

Comment: You can use a cron job for this.  Create a PHP script that resets the value, then call it at a specific time using cron.

Comment: @Dave I see I've never useed cron, i'll look into it, as for the adding INT's and limiting it to 100, how would this be done?

Comment: @SRC I added a good resource below, as for limiting the database value you'd have to bake that into your application logic, i.e. storing the database value + 1 and performing some specific code if it is above 100.

Comment: <?php
require 'db.php';
$data = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM `query`");
while( $assoc = mysqli_fetch_assoc($data)){
?>
Ok so how would I limit this query? to 10 let's say?

Comment: Also I only want to get the $assoc's in the query that have a certain value / text in them.

Comment: You should use MySQL's built-in LIMIT selector: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html. I know the documentation is verbose, but I highly recommend taking a quick pass through it so you're familiar with all of the things you can do directly through MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to set a cron job to reset the values every day. Here's a great resource to get started:

http://kb.iu.edu/data/afiz.html

Essentially, you display the crontab with

```
crontab -e
```

then add a command to execute at the specified frequency (the example below does example.php every day at midnight):

```
0 0 * * * /path/to/php /path/to/your/example.php
```

And in example.php you have the logic to reset the database values.

Answer (score 0):

Two options here:

1. Reset the counter with a cronjob at a specific time.
2. Don't have a counter, but create a log table and log each search with user-id and timestamp. Then, before executing a search, look up how many searches a user has done within the last 24 hours and decide if they're allowed to run another.